# Fill cells with a repetitive pattern in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have cells like 1,1,1,2,2,2. How do I use fill handle to continue to fill with 3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5 and so on? I have tried the fill series but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in **A1** enter:

```
=ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0)
```

and copy down.  For example:

[image]

There are other formulas to generate a variety of repeating patterns.

**EDIT#1:**

To get a repeating pattern of:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

use:

```
=MOD(ROW()-1,3)+1
```

and copy down.

To start with **0** rather then **1**, just subtract the last **1** in the formula.

Comment: Could you show me what other ways? I want to learn more.

Comment: I just learned a new thing. I can fill a series of weekdays only!!!

Comment: How do I go about fill something like 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3.....

Comment: @Meidi, something LIKE it?  `=MOD(ROW(),3)`  but EXACTLY that?  Gonna need IF logic: `=IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=0,3,MOD(ROW(),3))`

Comment: @Meidi.....See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 1):

It's actually fairly easy when you think about it.

1. In A1, type `1`.
2. In A2 type `=A1`.
3. In A3 type `=A1`.
4. Select the three of them and drag down.

It will get the desired result.

[image]